# Layered Navigation: Make some of the block collapsed by default

Tags: layered-navigation, magento-2.2.1

How to make some block (filters) of my choice collapsed by default? I have one attribute with a lot of values and it looks ugly.
Or, if this is not possible - maybe it's possible to make all of them collapsed by default?

**Note :**  Now all is expanded by default.

Comment: As per my knowledge in the default theme, all the attributes in layered navigation is by default "collapsed" only. Are you using any custom theme?Have you done any customization around layered navigation?

Answer (score 1):

1. Locate and Open this file(If you have not customized) - `vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\Magento_LayeredNavigation\templates\layer\view.phtml`
2. Go to line#36 which looks like this by default -

`<div class="filter-options" id="narrow-by-list" data-role="content" data-mage-init='{"accordion":{"openedState":"active", "collapsible": true, "active":false,"multipleCollapsible":false}}'>`

3. Make changes in data-mage-init as per your requirement.

You can also refer to some of the answers here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38904633/magento-2-expand-layered-navigation, however they are about having the filter expandable by default.